# deduplicating arrays in columns with mixed data types (Python)

Tags: python, arrays, duplicates

I have a dataframe with the mixed column datatypes that contain strings, arrays, ints. All the arrays are dtype=object.

```
>>> test = pd.DataFrame({'id': ['a','b','c', 'd'],
            'state': ['Arizona', np.array(['Texas', 'Texas', 'Texas']), 'Texas', np.array(['Texas', 'California'])],
            'zip': [91239, 21939, np.array([12941,13511]), np.array([11111, 11111, 11111])]})
    
>>> test
      id                  state                    zip
    0  a                Arizona                  91239
    1  b  [Texas, Texas, Texas]                  21939
    2  c                  Texas         [12941, 13511]
    3  d    [Texas, California]  [11111, 11111, 11111]
```

My desired output is to deduplicate arrays wherever they exist and when there are more than one different items in an array, to replace it with a string that says 'Multiple'

```
desired_output
  id     state       zip
0  a   Arizona     91239
1  b     Texas     21939
2  c     Texas  Multiple
3  d  Multiple     11111
```

I've tried to follow weird logic where I first create temp columns that count the number of unique items within a column, or that check if all() items in an array match the first indexed item, but these are all breaking. Thanks for any help!

Comment: How come the state in the second row changed from an array to a single word?

Comment: Hey Amirhossein, thanks for looking! It's because all the elements in the array are identical, so I want it to flatten to it's unique and singular value. I have other rows that are like [Texas, Texas, Texas...] that I still want to end up as one string, but others like [Texas, Texas, California] to then switch to 'Multiple'. This is true for the zip codes too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are interested in changing the lists in the **zip** and **state** column to *Multiple*, I suggest you to define a function and the apply this function on the column using [`pd.DataFrame.apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html). You can use the code below:

```py
def correctValue(value):
  if isinstance(value, (np.ndarray, list)):
    if len(value) > 1:
      if len(set(value)) == 1:
        return value[0]
      else:
        return "Multiple"
    elif len(value) == 1:
      return value[0]
  else:
    return value
test["zip"] = test["zip"].apply(correctValue)
test["state"] = test["state"].apply(correctValue)
test
```

##### Output

|  | id | state | zip |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | a | Arizona | 91239 |
| 1 | b | Texas | 21939 |
| 2 | c | Texas | Multiple |
| 3 | d | Multiple | 11111 |

Comment: I was able to modify your function to my desired output, thanks a ton!!

Comment: @dtsoi Glad to help. Although you have managed to solve the problem with the code, I edited the answer as per your comments.